# PDO inserting double data

Tags: php, pdo

My code is working, except it's inserting double data into the database, for example, if i type in john for username, and 123 for password, it insert it twice! how can i get rid of it?

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        require 'core/connect.php';

        $query = dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES(?,?)");

        $query->bindParam(1, $_POST['username']);
        $query->bindParam(2, $_POST['password']);
        $query->execute();

        if ($query->execute()) {
        echo 'Thank you! you may now log in <a href=\'index.php\'>here</a>';
        } else {
        echo 'Please go back, something was wrong.';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you run this twice

```
$query->execute();

if ($query->execute()) {
```

omit the first line

so you stay with:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    require 'core/connect.php';

    $query = dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES(?,?)");

    $query->bindParam(1, $_POST['username']);
    $query->bindParam(2, $_POST['password']);

    if ($query->execute()) {
        echo 'Thank you! you may now log in <a href=\'index.php\'>here</a>';
    } else {
        echo 'Please go back, something was wrong.';
    }
}
```